# Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '29449,29446,29450,29534' to data type int

Tags: sql

I am create a stored procedure in SQL and I get the following error when I execute the query:

> Conversion failed when converting the nvarchar value '11021,78542,12456,24521' to data type int.

Any idea why?

```
SELECT 
    A.Art_ID, A.Title
FROM 
    Art A
INNER JOIN 
    Iss I ON A.Iss_ID = I.Iss_ID
INNER JOIN 
    Sections S ON A.Section_ID = S.Section_ID
INNER JOIN 
    iPadSec IPS ON A.Sec_ID = IPS.Sec_ID
WHERE 
    A.Art_ID IN (SELECT CAST(Art_IDs AS int) /***error happens here***/
                 FROM Book_Art b
                 WHERE Sub_ID = 68)
    AND I.Iss > dateadd(month, -13, getdate())
    AND A.Active = 1
    AND IPS.Active = 1
    AND A.PDate <= getdate()
ORDER BY 
    PDate DESC, Art_ID DESC;
```

Comment: `11021,78542,12456,24521` is not an integer.

Comment: How could it convert that string to an `INT`, what's value do you expect as a result?

Comment: first split it and then convert

Comment: Guessing that Art_IDs is an external variable. Just have it as `WHERE A.Art_ID IN (Art_IDs)` and check that

Comment: When I manually do this WHERE A.Art_ID IN (11021,78542,12456) it works fine.

Comment: External variable will be the Sub_ID = 68. 68 will be replaced with an external variable.

Comment: Which dbms? (When having product specific functionality it's a very good idea to tag properly!)

Comment: I already solved it. Solution at the end

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Adding this line works for me.

```
declare @ids varchar(1000)
select @ids = art_ids from book_art where sub_id = @Sub_ID

EXECUTE ( 'SELECT A.Art_ID, A.Title'
        + ' FROM Art A'
        + ' INNER JOIN Iss I ON A.Iss_ID = I.Iss_ID'
        + ' INNER JOIN Sections S ON A.Section_ID = S.Section_ID'
        + ' INNER JOIN iPadSec IPS ON A.Sec_ID = IPS.Sec_ID'
        + ' WHERE A.Art_ID IN (' + @ids + ')'
        + ' AND I.Iss > dateadd(month, -13, getdate())'
        + ' AND A.Active = 1'
        + ' AND IPS.Active = 1'
        + ' AND A.PDate <= getdate()'
        + ' ORDER BY PDate DESC,'
        + ' Art_ID DESC;' 
    )
END
```

Thank you all for your help :)

Answer (score 2):

You cannot do what you want using `in`.  First, it is a really bad idea to store ids in lists in strings.  You should be using a junction table.

That said, sometimes this is necessary.  You can rewrite this line of code as:

```
EXISTS (SELECT 1 /***error happens here***/
        FROM Book_Art b
        WHERE Sub_ID = 68 AND
             ',' + Art_IDs + ',' LIKE '%,' + cast(A.Art_ID as varchar(255)) + ',%'
       )
```

However, the performance would generally be on the lousy side and there is little prospect of speeding this up without fixing the data structure.  Use a junction table instead of a string to store lists.

Comment: Actually I am using a junction table but I decide to store the Art_ids in one column instead of creating million row. I figure when users add a new art_id it will append to that column this way I have one sub_id instead of 300 million. Do you get what I am trying to do? I get an error running your code 'Expect ( after Exist but when i insert it doesn't work.